# Hibernate JPA IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for class with @embeddedid

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I am having trouble mapping my database domain model to the program entities in one case where the entity is essentially a join table (a period) which combines two other entities (a timeslot and a day). Another entity (a lesson) then has a reference to this period entity, determining when it occurs.

When I try to save a lesson with a new period using `saveOrUpdate(lesson)` hibernate throws an IdentifierGenerationException

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.trials.domain.Period

The database looks like below (not the real database, just the key tables and columns)

[image]

In the java hibernate model, I have used an embedded id for the primary key of the period class and the lesson class then has a reference to a period.

**Period.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "period")
public class Period{
    @EmbeddedId
    private PeriodId periodId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "day_idday", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Day day;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "timeslot_idtimeslot", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Timeslot timeslot;

    //constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, and equals
}
```

And the embedded id just has the primary key columns:

**PeriodId.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class PeriodId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "timeslot_idtimeslot")
    private int timeslotId;

    @Column(name = "day_idday")
    private int dayId;

    //constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, and equals
}
```

Then there is the lesson class that uses the period defined as:

**Lesson.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lesson")
public class Lesson {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idlesson")
    private int lessonId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "period_timeslot_idtimeslot", nullable = false, updatable = false), @JoinColumn(name = "period_day_idday", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Period period;
    //constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, and equals
}
```

The Timeslot and Day entity classes are both very basic pojos, and their ids use `GenerationType.AUTO`. So my problems are:

1. What causes this IdentifierGenerationException
2. How to avoid it while keeping the same database model

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [NULL ID Generated Via @GeneratedValue On Composite Key Using @EmbeddedId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088776/null-id-generated-via-generatedvalue-on-composite-key-using-embeddedid)

Comment: @Xstian I have read many SO questions on similar issues including that question answer and it is NOT like my problem. I am not manually managing any keys, just using an embedded id in a way that at first seemed straight forward

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put those guys

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "day_idday", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Day day;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "timeslot_idtimeslot", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Timeslot timeslot;
```

inside the PeriodId class and throw away those ints. I have done a mapping similar to yours this way and it works.

Comment: OK, I did this in the PeriodId class and marked the original properties @transient in the Period class. Then delegated the getters and setters in the period class to set and fetch their values from the embedded periodId

Comment: I tried your approach but now im getting  Data truncation: Data too long for column 'dalekComponent' at row 1.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "throw away those ints"? Do I keep the  `Timeslot` and `Day` in `Lesson` and remove the `int Ids` in `PeriodId`? What is the way to use @Transient?which property will be transient if I move them to PeriodId?

Comment: @MohammedIdris The ints that are int the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create the following mapping for my case (scala code) and could totally throw away the @Embeddable class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_order_item", schema = "pg")
@IdClass(classOf[PaymentOrderItem])
final class PaymentOrderItem extends Serializable{

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  var orderItem: OrderItem = _

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  var payment: Payment = _
}
```

So the following should work for you then

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "period")
@IdClass(Period.class)
public class Period extends Serializable{

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "day_idday", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Day day;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "timeslot_idtimeslot", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Timeslot timeslot;

    //constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, and equals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance,
You're missing the generated value annotation in the embedded id class.

```
@Embeddable
public class PeriodId implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "timeslot_idtimeslot")
    private int timeslotId;

    @GeneratedValue    
    @Column(name = "day_idday")
    private int dayId;

    //constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, and equals
}
```