# .IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following tables :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5419345600310440297L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cust")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cust", sequenceName = "cust_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<CustomerDeal> customerDeals;

    //getters and setters goes here ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DEALS")
public class Deals implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7197428343863081750L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "deals_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "deals_seq", sequenceName = "DEALS_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "DEAL_ID")
    private Long dealId;

    @Column(name = "DEAL_NAME")
    private String dealColName;

    //getters setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_DEALS")
public class CustomerDeals implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4249326793843278525L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomerDealId customerDealId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customers customers;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEAL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Deals deals;

   //getters setters

}

@Embeddable
public class CustomerDealId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9086627167426987610L;

    @Column(name = "DEAL_ID")
    private Long dealId;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Long customerId;

}
```

however when I try to create a new customer

```
Customer cust - new Customer ()
cust.setName("Foo")
CustomerDeals custDeals = new CustomerDeals()
Set<CustomerDeal>  custDealsSet = new HashSet<CustomerDeal> 
CustomerDeal custDealsSet1 = new CustomerDeal()
CustomerDeal custDealsSet2 = new CustomerDeal()
custDealsSet1.setDeals(dealsRepository.findOne(1))//getting existing deal
custDealsSet1.customers(cust)
custDealsSet2.setDeals(dealsRepository.findOne(2))//getting existing deal
custDealsSet2.customers(cust)
custDealsSet.add(custDealsSet1) 
custDealsSet.add(custDealsSet2) 
cust.setCustomerDeals(custDealsSet)
customerRepository.saveAndFlush(cust)
    customerRepository.saveAndFlush(cust)
```

I am getting

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated
>   for:class CustomerDeal

This is not duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295054/hibernate-jpa-identifiergenerationexception-null-id-generated-for-class-with-e)

Comment: What DB are you using? What does your persistence.xml look like?

Comment: @DirkSchumacher I am using Oracle DB , without persistence.xml

Comment: a) Does the DB have a sequence with the name DEALS_SEQ? b) Is it even possible to have it properly running without the persistence.xml due to the definitions of entitymanagerfactory and persistence units?

Comment: @DirkSchumacher yes, and deals are created , please note that in the example that I posted I am not creating new "deals" but I am using existing one. b) yes, you can define the relations by annotation

Comment: I am aware that the design of the data schema can be completly done by annotations. I was just wondering about persistence-units and EntityManagerFactorys. But since it works so far that can't be issue here and your conversion in the first answer will help more.

Answer (score 2):

Your code that throws exception does not make sense so I guess it is not real code.

CustomerDeal has composite key, so you would not be able to retrieve it with `dealsRepository.findOne(1)`, which means that you probably were retrieveing Deal not CustomerDeal but then the part would never compile:

```
Set<CustomerDeal>  custDealsSet = new HashSet<CustomerDeal>();
custDealsSet.add(dealsRepository.findOne(1))
```

So, apart from that, I guess you were retrieving the existing deals. And you made a new customer. As the key of CustomerDeal depeneds on both customer and deal, both custumer and deal have to be set before persisting it which you probably forgot to do (and you got your exception). So it should look like:

```
Customer cust - new Customer ();
cust.setName("Foo");

CustomerDeals custDeal = new CustomerDeals();
custDeal.setCustomer(cust);
custDeal.setDeal(dealsRepository.findOne(1));
cust.getCustomerDeals().add(custDeal);

custDeal = new CustomerDeals();
custDeal.setCustomer(cust);
custDeal.setDeal(dealsRepository.findOne(2));
cust.getCustomerDeals().add(custDeal);

customerRepository.saveAndFlush(cust);
```

Now you are probably still in trouble. If you override the equals and hash on CustomerDeal so they are ID based (which typical code generator for entities does), both new CustomerDeals instances have them as null, so when you add them to the set the second one will override the first inserted (as null ids will be equals).

You also need to inform JPA that the ID will come from the relations.
In your CustomerDea you need to add `@MapsId` annotation (on both joins), like:

```
@MapsId("customerId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Customers customers;
```

Finally, unless your CustomerDeal table contains additional apart from CUSTOMER_ID and Deal_ID, then, it is a simple joint table and should not be mapped at all. That way you will save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I did fix the code. I do need to add some additional info. I am new to hibernate and jpa. so if you can add links or example, it will be great.

Comment: It is not your orginal code as it does not have ; at the ends. Could you paste the real code please or use mine and confirm that you still get the exception. Do you have any need for the CustomerDeal entity, does it have any properties?

Comment: Also add the missing MapsId annotation like in the edited answer

Comment: you got me there, it is a code that emulates the real entities that I'm using . since I usually writes in scala I have the habit of not putting ; at the end. however the real code it in java but I cannot paste it here (but I edit it according to your comments in the original post). however I did tried your code but on cust.getCustomerDeals().add(custDeal); I am getting NullPointerException on cust.getCustomerDeals() which make sense since it is newly created customer

Comment: yeah, my habit, in my getCollections methods always create new one if null. Highly recommend it though, it is also done same way by jaxb or jpa code generators. If you are sure that both customer and the deal are set on new entity that is fine. Add the missing MapsId!!!.

Comment: IIUC the MapsId annotation should map to embedded class field (i.e customerId ) however doing so yields org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [CustomerDeals.customers]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73668/discussion-between-igx-and-zielu).

Comment: I missed your chat invite. Do you initlize the CustomerDealId in CustomerDeal so it is not null when you create new CustomerDeal. I belive that in JPA2, you can move both id fields directly to CustomerDeal without using embedable.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you got the error mentioned above is due to a mapping issue(I cant figure out what exactly is wrong though). As a completely different approach, I have modified your mappings. I have tested this and it is working fine. The advantage for you with this mapping is that it makes the `CustomerDeals` class redundant. Please note that I have removed the sequences as I am using MySQL.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5419345600310440297L;

   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
   private Long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
        name="CUSTOMER_DEALS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="CUSTOMER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="DEAL_ID")
 )
 private Set<Deals> deals = new HashSet<Deals>();
   //Setters and Getters to follow
    }
```

The Deals Class will be

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEALS")
public class Deals implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7197428343863081750L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DEAL_ID")
    private Long dealId;

    @Column(name = "DEAL_NAME")
    private String dealColName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "deals")
    private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>(0);
//Setters and Getters here
}
```

Finally the main method which does the insert.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setName("NewCust2");

Deals deals = new Deals();
deals.setDealColName("Deal2");

customer.getDeals().add(deals);

customerRepository.save(customer);
```

Comment: hmm but this is OneToMany relation. and I am looking for ManyToMany relation. as Customer can have many deals AND in the same deal several customers can participate