# Many-to-many relationship using @EmbeddedId produces null id generated for:class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables that have a many to many relationship between them:

- Table one: Competition
- Relationship table: Entry
- Table two: User

The entry table is using an `@EmbeddedId`:

```
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Entry {

    @EmbeddedId
    EntryKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("competition_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "competition_id")
    private Competition competition;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("user_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    private Integer number;
}
```

where `EntryKey` is implemented as:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntryKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "competition_id")
    Integer competitionId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    Integer userId;
}
```

The `Competition` and `User` entities also contain the inverse references:

**Competition**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "competition")
private Set<Entry> entries;
```

**User**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Entry> entries;
```

The issue is when executing the following post request (maybe this is wrong?):

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "competition_id": 2,
    "number": 1
}
```

...which is being picked up in this controller:

```
@PostMapping
public Entry create(@RequestBody Entry entry) {
    return entryRepo.save(entry);
}
```

A `IdentifierGenerationException` is thrown: `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.mw.API.Entities.Entry`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295054/hibernate-jpa-identifiergenerationexception-null-id-generated-for-class-with-e) however none of the answers seemed to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the EntryKey is not getting bound by the request.Sending this

```
{
    "competition":{
            "competitionId":6   
    },
    "user":{
        "userId":5
    },
    "number": 1
}
```

instead of this

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "competition_id": 2,
    "number": 1
}
```

Should bind the values properly.